# Python: programatically add a specific number of spaces to the beginning of a string

Tags: python

I need to add spaces to the beginning of a string based on a character entered by the user.

For example. if the user entered 5, then 5 spaces would need to be added to the beginning of the string.

I realise I can do this with a loop, but this seams like quite a bit of code, is there a ore pythonic method to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the number has been input, you can add that many spaces to the string like this:

```
string = ' ' * howmany + string
```

This makes a string of `howmany` times the space and adds it to the front of the original string.